# Julia beginner: Iterate getindex() for increasing indices

Tags: julia

I'm working with a 121x137 (i,j) array (mortality table) and am trying to create a 121x1 vector from this made up of the (i+1,j+1) values (i.e. index (50,50), (51,51) and so forth.

I'm using the following code - BaseTable is my 121x137 array:

```
age=50    
survivalcurve = for i in age:nrow(BaseTable)-1
    for j in age:ncol(BaseTable)-1
        println(getindex(FemaleBaseTable, i+1, j+1))
    end
    end
```

However, when I do this, its returning all values of i and j - if I picture the values I want as a diagonal line running top-bottom, L-R of my table, its giving me all the values on the top right of my imaginary diagonal line.

If I fix i and loop through j, it works and returns the entire 50th row:

```
age=50
survivalcurve =
    for j in age:ncol(FemaleBaseTable)
        println(getindex(FemaleBaseTable, 50, j+1))
    end
```

and likewise if I fix j and loop through i, this works and returns the entire jth column:

```
age=50

survivalcurve =
    for i in age:nrow(FemaleBaseTable)-1
        println(getindex(FemaleBaseTable, i+1, 50))
    end
```

I've surmised its returning all values because I'm using age:nrow / age:ncol, but not sure what a suitable replacement would be to only return the (i+1),(j+1) value would be.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not simply `diag(FemaleBaseTable)`? Is that what you want?

Comment: This is progress, thank you - however Diag seems to only accept the starting column not starting row as well, but I need to specify the start row based on age -  I can probably subset the DF/Matrix based on age for one life/age... but will need to ponder how to expand this to cope with multiple ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the diagonal elements starting at any index `(i,j)` by using either `diag` from `LinearAlgebra.jl` or manually using a single loop.

Assuming you have:

```
nrows, ncols = 121, 137
FemaleBaseTable = rand(nrows, ncols)

# And the diagonal should start at any (i,j)
i, j = 50, 50
```

You can either use

```
diag(@view FemaleBaseTable[i:end,j:end])
```

or,

```
[FemaleBaseTable[i,i] for (i,j) in zip(i:nrows,j:ncols)]
```